# How to add STL support in AIDE

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk, aide-ide

I try to use the STL But it says *string: no such file or directory*

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
APP_ABI:=all
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
include    $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename your source file `hello-jni.c` to `hello-jni.cpp`, if you don't want to mess up with `gcc` behavior.

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
APP_ABI := all
```